Deriving the general expression for spherical harmonics in Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics
In Skurai, J. J., Modern Quantum Mechanics 3rd Edition, it is mentioned in passing that given the form of
$$Y^l_l(\theta,\phi) = \frac{(-1)^l}{2^l l!}\sqrt{\frac{(2l+1)!}{4\pi}}e^{il\phi} \sin^l\theta, $$
we could apply the lowering operator to it multiple times to arrive at the final expression
$$ Y^m_l(\theta,\phi) = \frac{(-1)^l}{2^l l!}\sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{4\pi} \frac{(l+m)!}{(l-m)!}}e^{im\phi}\frac{1}{\sin^m\theta} \frac{\mathrm{d}^{l-m}}{\mathrm{d}(\cos\theta)^{l-m}}\left(\sin^{2l}\theta\right). \tag{1}$$
I started with the relation
$$ L_{-}\vert l,m\rangle = \hbar\sqrt{(l-m)(l+m+1)}\vert l,m-1\rangle, $$
then let the direction bra $\langle \hat{\mathbf{n}} \vert$ act on it:
$$ \langle \hat{\mathbf{n}} \vert L_{-}\vert l,m\rangle = -i\hbar e^{-i\phi}\left(-i\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} - \cot\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\right) \left\langle \hat{\mathbf{n}} \middle| l, m\right\rangle = \hbar\sqrt{(l-m)(l+m+1)}\left\langle \hat{\mathbf{n}} \middle| l, m-1\right\rangle. $$
Iterating this I get
$$ Y^m_l(\theta, \phi) = \frac{(-1)^l}{2^l l!}\sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{4\pi} \frac{(l+m)!}{(l-m)!}}\left[ e^{-i\phi}\left(-\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} + i\cot\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\right) \right]^{l-m} e^{il\phi}\sin^l\theta, \tag{2}$$
but I have no idea how to expand the [] term to get the desired form.
Edit: I don't think this question should be closed. Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics is an important textbook in undergraduate and graduate physics, and since it is not unheard of on this site to have questions clarifying certain skipped computations in Jackson or Sakurai, I think this particular question would be of great help for future students (including myself!) studying the book.

Have you tried one step down? What snags?

Applying $L_{-}$ once, I get a term proportional to $-2l e^{i(l-1)\phi} \sin^{l-1}\theta \cos\theta$; applying twice I get $2l(l-1) e^{i(l-2)\phi} \left( 2\sin^{l-2}\theta\cos^2 \theta - \sin^l\theta \right)$. But I don't see a clear pattern afterwards.

So you confirm this, but you don't like the pattern?

It's fuzzy in my head, but I think variations of Rodrigues Formulas might apply. You can often express a differential operator as a product of other operators. Further, those factors can be changed to get a raising or lowering operator. For example, for Hermite polynomials you start with $(\hat{D}-2x)\hat{D}$. Those factors can be used to generate further solutions. I think something similar is possible for spherical harmonics.

@CosmasZachos Yes, numerically I can confirm the equations are correct. But I would like to know how to simplify my equation into the desired Rodriguez-like formula given in the book.

There is apparently no simple expression for the expansion of the lowering operator, or at least none is given in the bible for this:

Varshalovich, Dmitriĭ Aleksandrovich, Anatolï Nikolaevitch Moskalev, and Valerij Kel'manovǐc Khersonskii. Quantum theory of angular momentum. World scientific, 1988.

Varshalovich does give several expressions in terms of differential operators in section 5.2.1, similar to the one you give,
but interestingly none have the form of the repeated action of a a lowering operator.
Note that your Eq.(1) starts with $2\ell$ powers of $\sin\theta$ whereas your (2) starts with only $\ell$ powers of $\sin\theta$.  Thus it appears unlikely that (2) can be rejigged into (1) without multiplying by factors that would obscure the action of the lowering operators in (2).

Note that Varshalovich has a slightly different differential form than your (initial) expression:
$$
Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\phi)=\frac{e^{im\phi}}{2^\ell \ell!} \sqrt{\frac{2\ell+1}{4\pi} \frac{(\ell+m)!}{(\ell-m)!} }(\sin(\theta))^{-m} \frac{d^{\ell-m}}{(d\cos\theta)^{\ell-m}}
\left(\cos^2\theta -1\right)^\ell\, 
$$
so they have an extra factor $\sin(\theta)^{-m}$ that you did't have but have now corrected.

Apart from the $(-1)^l$ factor which I suppose is due to convention, there is indeed a $ (\sin^m \theta)^{-1} $ factor which I missed.

@JonathanHuang the $(-1)^\ell$ comes because $(\cos^2\theta-1)^\ell=(-1)^\ell\sin^{2\ell}\theta$.  I see you have inserted a $\sin^{-m}(\theta)$.  The main difference is that the differential expressions of Varshalovich takes derivatives of $\sin^{2\ell}(\theta)$  whereas the lowering expressions takes derivatives of $\sin^\ell(\theta)$. It is likely impossible or at least very highly non-trivial to go from one to the other.

Yes, the Varshalovich (and Sakurai) expression seems unobvious from the lowering operator expression. This is unfortunately the main concern of my question.

@JonathanHuang I do not think it’s possible to go from one to the other given the starting points are so different.

To expand it, you need to do it recursively. First, note that
$$
\left( -{\partial\over \partial \theta} + i\cot \theta {\partial\over \partial \phi}\right) e^{il\phi}F(\theta) = -\left( {\partial\over \partial \theta} +l\cot \theta \right) e^{il\phi}F(\theta) = -{1\over (\sin\theta)^l}{\partial\over \partial \theta} (\sin\theta)^l e^{il\phi}F(\theta) \equiv e^{il\phi}F_1(\theta)
$$
For any function $F$, and I defined the function $F_1$ conveniently. Now applying twice
$$
\left( {\partial\over \partial \theta} + i\cot \theta {\partial\over \partial \phi}\right)^2 e^{il\phi}F(\theta) = \left( {\partial\over \partial \theta} + i\cot \theta {\partial\over \partial \phi}\right) e^{il\phi}F_1(\theta) =  -{1\over (\sin\theta)^l}{\partial\over \partial \theta} (\sin\theta)^l e^{il\phi}F_1(\theta) 
$$
If you substitute the expression of $F_1$, you would get
$$
\left( {\partial\over \partial \theta} + i\cot \theta {\partial\over \partial \phi}\right)^2 e^{il\phi}F(\theta) = {1\over (\sin\theta)^l}\left({\partial\over \partial \theta}\right)^2 (\sin\theta)^l e^{il\phi}F(\theta).
$$
In general, you'll end with a recurrence
$$
F_n(\theta) = \left( {\partial\over \partial \theta} + i\cot \theta {\partial\over \partial \phi}\right)e^{il\theta}F_{n-1}(\theta),
$$
where the functions $F_n$ could be written as a derivative.

I don't know any other method to open terms like that. But it generally works.
